# JQuery resizable move in one direction, and remove scroll bars

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jquery `resizable` to resize a div

```
$( "div" ).resizable();
```

I have one section and a `div` inside it with scrollable content. I am facing couple of problems.

1. I want to resize in one direction y-axis only
2. When I scroll the inner div, the resize handler icon (on the right below corner) should not scroll with the content
3. While scrolling the inner div, if all content is visible, scrollbars should be disappear,

How it is possible with jquery ui resizable, or there any plugin other than this that can do this job.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k6r5P/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For resizing the div in the y axis only. You could also remove the `if` condition if you like

Try

```
$( ".contenteditable" ).resizable({
    create:function(event,ui){//for setting overflow

        if($(this)[0].scrollHeight > parseInt($(this).css('height'),10)){

            $('.contenteditable').css('overflow','auto');
        }
    },
    resize: function(event,ui){ //for restricting x-axis resize
        if(ui.size.width>250){
            ui.size.width = ui.originalSize.width;
        }
    }
});
```

And for moving the resize icon try

```
$( ".contenteditable" ).scroll(function(e){

    var newH = $(this).scrollTop() + parseInt($(this).css('height'),10);
    if(newH > $(this)[0].scrollHeight){
        newH = $(this)[0].scrollHeight;
    }
    $(this).css('height',newH+'px');
});
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/k6r5P/6/)